# sort array of arrays in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have an array that is created like this:

```
$i = 0;

$files = array();   

while ($file = mysql_fetch_array($query_files)) {
    $files[$i] = array();
    $files[$i] = $file;
    $i++;
}
```

And I need to be able to sort the $files array based on each $file['name'] aka $files[$i]['name'].

How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: you mean alphabetically?

Comment: Would it not be easier to do the ordering in SQL (`ORDER BY name`)?

Comment: You could sort the data from your SQL query with "ORDER BY ..."

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: ^ It's been a while since i've seen this comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `ORDER BY NAME` to your query. Seriously. That's the fastest, memory safest and all around best way to do it. I'm not kidding. Further, you'd be telling the database to do something it is awesome at, whereas PHP is only OK at it. Finally, you have the option to index the name column of the DB while PHP offers no index.

If you absolutely *must* sort it yourself, then you need to use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
// this example is almost a clone of something in the docs.
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}
usort($files, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
   if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) {
       return 0;
   }
   return $a['name'] < $b['name'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```